# I cannot create settings activity

Tags: android, android-studio

When I goes to create settings activity i got a undefined error at android studio. I just  follow this actions: app folder->new->activity->settings activity. After input a necessary info I clicked finish button and got a error. Who faced with this case? How fix it?

[image]

Comment: Try to **clean** and **rebuild** project.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg, I already try it...it doesn't help

Comment: Then try manually adding activity.

Comment: Click on disable plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a third party plugin that fails in the background and/or affects the bundled Android Support plugin.

Go to Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins and show: Custom to see what 3rd party plugins you have. I suggest you turn them off momentarily.

Also, ensure you are running on the latest of the Android Studio IDE and not on Canary builds. You could also check for recent issues related to Android Studio on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:192708).

You may also try to invalidate your Android Studio caches.

---

**I discourage you from disabling the Android Support plugin, as that will take away some core functionalities that is shipped with the IDE**